# Select rows based on on a list of start and end dates

Tags: python-3.x

`DateTime,              units
2019-04-04 13:44:48,    15
2019-04-05 13:44:49,    95
2019-04-06 13:44:50,    16
2019-04-07 13:44:51,    23
2019-04-09 13:44:53,    17
2019-04-10 13:44:53,    54
2019-04-11 13:44:53,    14
2019-04-12 13:44:53,    53
2019-04-13 13:44:53,    82
2019-04-14 13:44:53,    25
2019-04-15 13:44:53,    66
2019-04-16 13:44:53,    2
2019-04-17 13:44:53,    44
2019-04-18 13:44:53,    85
2019-04-19 13:44:53,    28
2019-04-20 13:44:53,    20
2019-04-21 13:44:53,    99
2019-04-22 13:44:53,    41
2019-04-23 13:44:53,    3
2019-04-24 13:44:53,    36
2019-04-25 13:44:53,    26
2019-04-26 13:44:53,    30`


`Start,                    End
2019-04-01 00:00:00,    2019-04-06 00:00:00
2019-04-09 00:00:00,    2019-04-11 00:00:00
2019-04-18 00:00:00,    2019-04-21 00:00:00`

I have a large csv file (>5GB) and a list of start and end dates. I would like to select rows in the dataframe based on the list of start and end dates. The end and start dates don't overlap.

For the sample above the result would be

`DateTime,         units
2019-04-04 13:44:48,    15
2019-04-05 13:44:49,    95
2019-04-09 13:44:53,    17
2019-04-10 13:44:53,    54
2019-04-18 13:44:53,    85
2019-04-19 13:44:53,    28
2019-04-20 13:44:53,    20`

I can do this using a for loop but want something more efficient if possible.

Comment: Can you give an example of a row? Are there two separate columns for start and end dates?

Comment: The start and end dates are separate columns as above and the rows are as above.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use `pandas`. First you'll want to get your data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df = pd.read_csv("path-to-your-csv-file/yourfile.csv") # read your file to df

start = "2019-04-07 00:00:00" # example start date string converted
end = "2019-04-11 00:00:00" # example ending date string

to_datetime = lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") # format a string to a datetime object

df['DateTime'] = df.DateTime.apply(to_datetime) #convert the column entries from strings to datetime objects

# convert start and end date strings to date time objects
start = to_datetime(start) 
end = to_datetime(end)
```

Something like the `to_datetime` function is what you'll need almost in any case, because having the `DateTime` column hold datetime objects really comes in handy. The simplest case is when you don't care about the hours and we assume that the dates are valid:

```py
df.DateTime = df.DateTime.dt.date # get rid of the timestamps
start_index = df[df.DateTime == start.date()].index[0] # get the index of the first column where DateTime == start
end_index = df[df.DateTime == end.date()].index[-1] # get the index of the last column where DateTime == end

target = df[start_index:end_index + 1] # save a subset of df matching your criteria to target
```

If the dates are not valid (*e.g.*, because you want to have hours, but can't specify them precisely), you can make use of `searchsorted` to get the indices:

```py
start_index = df.DateTime.searchsorted(start)[0] # get the first index where DateTime is closest to start
end_index = df.DateTime.searchsorted(end)[-1] # get the latest index where DateTime is closest to end

target = df[start_index:end_index + 1] # save a subset of df matching your criteria to target
```

Be careful when using `searchsorted` though, don't forget to omit the step of removing timestamps and make sure that the `DateTime` column is sorted. Lastly, as `"2019-04-07 23:55:00"` will be closer to `"2019-04-09 13:00:00"` whereas `"2019-04-07 10:55:00"` will be closer to `"2019-04-07 13:00:00"` - in other words, timestamps matter.

Comment: Thanks Gasper. If I understand the code correctly you are using one pair of start and end dates. Unfortunately I have 1000's of intervals, so I don't think it will work. I think I will have to use a for loop to step through the time intervals.